# What is Significance of "protected Object value" in below code?

Tags: java, object, abstract-class

### **Not able to understand the significance of commented line...**

can someone help to understand the use of Object in this class, I couldn't get that

```
public abstract class ListItem {
protected ListItem rightLink = null;
protected ListItem leftLink = null;

protected Object value; //confused about this

public ListItem(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
}

abstract ListItem next();
abstract ListItem setNext(ListItem item);
abstract ListItem previous();
abstract ListItem setPrevious(ListItem item);

abstract int compareTo(ListItem item);

public Object getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(Object value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Comment: Well it's the value of the item in the list. Normally I'd expect this to be a generic class `ListItem<T>` and for the `value` field to be of type `T` (and all fields to be private rather than protected) though.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a double linke list, where `value` hold the actual list item and `leftLink` and `rightLink` are references to the left and right item. What is it that you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

`Object` in your case simply means, that the value of your `ListItem` can be nearly any Object. So for example the first ListItem can be of value `String`, the second one of `Integer` and so on. So if you get an ListItem out of the list, you don't know of which type it is, because it could be anything. But as already mentioned inside the comment from Jon, it would be better to use a generic `ListItem<T>` instead.